# Using ruby to automate tasks

Tags: ruby, bash, sed, grep, dsl

I would like to learn some scripting to help automate some common tasks. Is ruby a good language to learn for this and what gems will be useful?

I would like to make scripts similar to this bash script

http://nikhgupta.com/code/initialize-gitolite-bash-script/

Which automates setting up a new gitolite repo.

Would you just learn bash, sed grep etc?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a job for Ruby and Rake! Check [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-rubyrake/) out.
In my opinion, Python and Ruby are the best languages out there, when it comes to automating tasks in *NIX systems. Being a Windows buff, I'd stick to PowerShell..

Comment: From my experience, nothing comes close to Expect (Tcl) for automating unix or anything that needs telnet. It's ability to trick the called programming into believing there is a user at it's end is extremely useful. That being said, both Python and Ruby can be very good for it too.

Comment: Ah, I missed Tcl! So that's 3 choices to go in for.

Comment: turns out ruby even has a gem for gitolite https://github.com/wingrunr21/gitolite

Answer (score 0):

For Linux/Unix administration good shell scripting skills is essential. For more advanced automation, it is also good to know python, perl, or ruby. It really doesn't matter which you choose. Once you have become proficient with one, you will find that picking up the others to be an easy task.

Personally, ruby's package management system (gems) has always turned be off from using it from a scripting platform. Others hold different opinions and like it.

Pick one and dive in.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I would have recommended to use PERL for things like that. 
In my opinion it's always a good idea to have some base knowledge of shell scripting but if you really want to do something "bigger" use a script language (like Python, Ruby or Perl).

In meantime I see no reason to *not* use ruby for things like that. I really enjoy this language and you can do everything (?) that you could do in PERL in ruby as well (and you will have a real OO language at hand).

[CPAN](http://www.cpan.org) on the other hand is a quite nice argument to use PERL. Ruby gems are similar but I don't think there are that many gems as CPAN-modules available. But please compare by yourself (http://rubygems.org/).